# sort a string array by first two characters in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, string, sorting

I have a string array as strList = ["12abc", "23bcd", "12shsh", "23xyz"]
Is there any way to sort the array according to just first two characters of each string?

Comment: [Sort](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) by `prefix(2)`

Comment: Have you tried `strList.sorted()`?

Comment: How do you expect this sort by prefix to differ from plain `.sort()` or `.sorted()` results?

Comment: need to sort by prefix(2) but how to do in code?

Comment: @Maysam yes but it sort for full string.

Comment: *How to do in code?* This is very easy and very basic stuff. Please read the linked documentation and the [Swift Language Guide about closures](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html). There are examples how to use `sort(ed)` by closure.

Comment: @vadian it is not easy, sort by first 2 characters is unavailable in swift language guide.

Comment: It is easy. Please read also the duplicate, rather than `fileID` use `prefix(2)`

Answer (score 4):

just try this

```
var strList = ["12abc", "23bcd", "12shsh", "23xyz","13das","21dadsd"]
var sortArray = strList.sorted()
debugPrint(strList)
print(sortArray)
```

the console result will show in below

```
["12abc", "23bcd", "12shsh", "23xyz", "13das", "21dadsd"]
["12abc", "12shsh", "13das", "21dadsd", "23bcd", "23xyz"]
```

Comment: but if,  strList = ["12shsh", "23bcd", "12abc", "23xyz","13das","21dadsd"]  then the output will be 12shsh, 12abc..... So i need to sort by first 2 digit

Comment: Note that you cannot rely on the order of same-sorted elements, since Swift's sort algorithm does not guarantee a stable sort.